# Setting variable from URL in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to set part of the URL as a variable in PHP?

So for example if this was the URL:

```
http://domain.com/?=customer&p[1]=data&p[1]=admin_data&type_id=5&client_id=2345
```

Could I take the last segment of the URL which is `client_id=2345` and set the `2345` as a variable `$client_id`

Comment: yes extract your $_GET like extract($_GET)

Comment: this you can find on google, no?

Comment: wow everyone is so fast at night.

Comment: This might help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From url you use $_GET

```
$client_id = $_GET['client_id']
```

There is similar variable for data sent from form `$_POST`

Answer (score 2):

y, ofc, thats what $_GET is for:

```
$client_id = $_GET['client_id'];
```

Dont forget to validate pls, for example:

```
$client_id = filter_var($_GET['client_id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Comment: so does the filter strip anything that gets attached beyond the numbers following equal?

Comment: I dont know exactly how the Filter works tbh.^^ Its a predefined PHP function and makes sure that the input is valid. If you Filter with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`, you cant enter something like "hi im gosu" or whatever. For further information about filters, you should look at the php docs: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 1):

You can get parameter from url by `$_GET`($_GET is a php reserved variable) by parameter name.
format is :
`$_GET['parameter_name'];`

It seems that your url is not correctly formated:

```
http://domain.com/?=customer&p[1]=data&p[1]=admin_data&type_id=5&client_id=2345
```

it should be like this:

```
http://domain.com/?param_name=customer&p[1]=data&p[1]=admin_data&type_id=5&client_id=2345
```

Then you can get:

```
$var1 = $_GET['param_name'];
$client_id =  $_GET['client_id']; // get client id
```

here is the reference : http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
it will help you to understad.

let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 1):

See by yourself :

```
<?php
if (count ($_GET) == 0)
{
    // redirect with GET parameters
    $strange_get = "=customer&p[1]=data&p[1]=admin_data&type_id=5&a[1]->x=zz&b[1][2]=one&b[1][]=two"
    header ("Location:${_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?$strange_get");
    exit();
}
// see what we got
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [p] => Array
        (
            [1] => admin_data
        )
    [type_id] => 5
    [a] => Array
        (
            [1] => zz
        )
    [b] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => one
                    [3] => two
                ) 
        )
)
```

`customer` was ignored because no name was given
`p[1]` was set twice, so only the last value remained
`a[1]->x=zz` was interpreted as `a[1]=zz`
`b[1][2]` and `b[1][]` worked as expected

Arrays are the only things you can expect to work out of the box.

For instance, passing `"?index=10&value[index]=123"` will not interpret `index` magically